# lookup formula against multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In table 1, I need the 4th column to be the answer from table 2

basically i need to get a result in column d of table 1. I need to lookup column 1 in table 1 against column 1 in table 2 and if column 2 in table 1 is greater than or equal to column 2 in table 2 AND if column 3 in table 1 is equal to or less than column 3 in table 2 - then return column d from table 2 in table 1

desired outcome:
line 1 should contain a and b : line 2 should contain e : line 3 should be g h i : line 4 should be k l : line 5 should be m n

**First table**

[image: table 1]

As text:

| # | Year1 | Year2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 2022 |
| 2 | 2017 | 2021 |
| 3 | 2015 | 2022 |
| 4 | 2012 | 2019 |
| 5 | 2015 | 2021 |

**Second table**

[image: table 2]

As text

| # | Year1 | Year2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 2022 | a |
| 1 | 2016 | 2022 | b |
| 1 | 2017 | 2023 | c |
| 2 | 2016 | 2021 | d |
| 2 | 2017 | 2021 | e |
| 2 | 2017 | 2022 | f |
| 3 | 2015 | 2021 | g |
| 3 | 2015 | 2022 | h |
| 3 | 2016 | 2021 | i |
| 4 | 2011 | 2018 | j |
| 4 | 2012 | 2018 | k |
| 4 | 2012 | 2019 | l |
| 5 | 2015 | 2019 | m |
| 5 | 2016 | 2021 | n |
| 5 | 2017 | 2022 | o |

Comment: could you please post desired output too? I struggle to understand your question currently

Comment: basically i need to get a result in column d of table 1. I need to lookup column 1 in table 1 against column 1 in table 2 and if column 2 in table 1 is greater than or equal to column 2 in table 2 AND if column 3 in table 1 is equal to or less than column 3 in table 2 - then return column d from table 2 in table 1

Comment: line1 should contain a and b : line 2 should contain e : line 3 should be g h i : line 4 should be k l : line 5 should be m n

Comment: please edit your question with expected results instead of answering in comment. That'd be easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

If your version of Excel contains the [**TEXTJOIN() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c), then the task is quite simple.

A formula like

`{=TEXTJOIN(";";1;IF(($F$2:$F$16=A2)*($G$2:$G$16<=B2)*($H$2:$H$16>=C2);$I$2:$I$16;""))}`

will do just that: it will test each condition and create an array like *{YES, NO, NO, YES...}*. Multiplying these arrays will give "YES" only for those rows in which all conditions are met.

Now, using the normal [**IF() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2), return the values ​​of the fourth column for true values ​​and empty strings for false values.

The TEXTJOIN() function will concatenate all non-empty values ​​into one string and skip empty values ​​(the second parameter of the function takes care of that).

[image: Result]

Keep in mind that this is an array formula - the input should be completed by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of the usual Enter

*Unfortunately, I can’t check the correctness of the formula - my version of Excel didn’t know TEXTJOIN() yet, I constructed the formula in [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download-libreoffice/) - some additional steps may be required to make this work in Excel, such as wrapping each condition in an [**N() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/n-function-a624cad1-3635-4208-b54a-29733d1278c9)*

```
{=TEXTJOIN(";";1;IF(N($F$2:$F$16=A2)*N($G$2:$G$16<=B2)*N($H$2:$H$16>=C2);$I$2:$I$16;""))}
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this, however looking at the formula, row 2 should only contain "e" as d is before 2017 and f is after 2021

Comment: line1 should contain a and b

line 3 should be g h i

line 4 should be k l 

line 5 should be m n

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood which period should go into which period - Year1-Year2 of the first table inside Year1-Year2 of the second table or vice versa. Just reverse the selection conditions: **<=** to **>=** and **>=** to **<=** - `=TEXTJOIN(";";1;IF(N($F$2:$F$16=A2)*N($G$2:$G$16>=B2)*N($H$2:$H$16<=C2);$I$2:$I$16;""))`

Comment: And how would you read ***"the date range in column 3 is equal to or less than that in column 3"*** if you were not the author of this phrase? :-)

Comment: neither I can't validate your formula, just a comment: versions of Excel having TEXTJOIN also automatically recognise array formulae. Don't need to use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER anymore

Comment: I think you are close - closer than me perhaps --- basically i need to get a result in column d of table 1. I need to lookup column 1 in table 1 against column 1 in table 2 and if column 2 in table 1 is greater than or equal to column 2 in table 2 AND if column 3 in table 1 is equal to or less than column 3 in table 2 - then return column d from table 2 in table 1

Answer (score 0):

here is a formula giving you the desired output (however your description have the greater than / less than relations differently)

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, FILTER(Table2[Value],(Table2[n]=[@n])*(Table2[Year1]>=[@Year1])*(Table2[Year2]<=[@Year2]),""))`

[image]

Comment: any chance you can use cell references instead example Not "(Table2[Value]" I am trying to learn this and it will help - thanks

Comment: @Andy I've added that formula too.